# Using 'DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)' properly with Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to run this query with Codeigniter:

```
SELECT * FROM `bf_bs_history` WHERE date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
```

If I enter it directly in phpMyAdmin, I get the result I want. However, running if from the code, it will not take any effect. It's not filtering at all. 
The PHP line looks like this:

```
$this->history_model->where(array('date > ' => 'DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)'))->find_all();
```

Any idea where I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter Active Record is adding backticks to your statement, which renders your clause as a string, not an executable function. You can set a second parameter to `false` to stop that. Also, for a function predicate like this you can simply pass in the string:

```
$this->history_model->where("date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)", false)->find_all();
```

Comment: It works without the array, but actually I have another condition there, I just didn't mention it above:
'id'=> $this->current_user->id.
If I use an array, it just won't work, no matter if I set a second parameter to false.
I wonder if I could put it in there in one statement using an AND somehow?

Comment: Okay, I have figured it out: I can just use it like this:
->where('id', $this->current_user->id)->where("date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)")

Comment: @user3791132 Yep, you got it, you can method chain Active Record methods. If the answer helped you, feel free to up vote.

Comment: It seems I can"t because I'm new.